# Как сделать интерполяцию или (аппроксимацию?), чтобы график был плавным, но в тоже время проходил через заданные координаты точек

Tags: matlab

```
 clear, clc
 X=[240 0 -240];
 Y=[0 -3 0];
 Z=[0 0 0];

 plot3(X, Y, Z, '-o');
 xlabel('X')
 ylabel('Y')
 zlabel('Z')
 grid on
```

Comment: Используйте интерполяционные сплайны (что-какое оно есть в матлабе - не знаю)

Answer (score 0):

Так как координаты по Z везде равны 0, то можно использовать функцию spline

```
clear, clc
X=[240 0 -240];
Y=[0 -3 0];
Z=[0 0 0];
xx=linspace(-240,240);
yy=spline(X,Y,xx);
zz=zeros(1,length(xx));
plot3(X, Y, Z, 'o');
hold on
plot3(xx,yy,zz)
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
zlabel('Z')
grid on
```